# ¿Cómo estructuro correctamente mi código para POO en Typesccript?

Tags: poo, typescript

## Problema en TypeScript

Tengo tres clases, donde la principal es `Marcianos` que se instancia una única vez y que las demás clases podrán acceder la información de esa única instancia.

Tengo otra clase `Computadora` que se encarga de crear marcianos mediante del método `creaMarcianos()`.

La otra clase es `Jugador` que se encarga de destruir los marcianos mediante el método `destruirMarciano()`.

Por último la clase `Juego` que implementa todas estas clases e inicia el proceso.

Mi problema es que al llamar a los métodos de las clases no se ejecutan es decir, al llamar `juagdor.destruirMarciano()` no disminuye la cantidad de los marcianos ni ejecuta por consola el mensaje por defecto.

## Código

```
class Marcianos{
//Unico objeto
private static _marciano: Marcianos=null;
private static cantidad: number;
private constructor(){
    //Números de marcianos al inicio
    Marcianos.cantidad=10;

    if(Marcianos._marciano){
        throw new Error("Error: La instanciación fallo, use Marcianos.crearMarcianos para crear una nueva instancia");
    }
    Marcianos._marciano=this;
}

public static getMarcianos(): Marcianos{
    if(Marcianos._marciano===null){
        Marcianos._marciano=new Marcianos();
    }
    return Marcianos._marciano;
}

public derribaMarcianos(): void{
    console.log('Soy el bueno, derribe un marciano');
    if(Marcianos.cantidad>0)
        Marcianos.cantidad--;
}

public creaMarcianos():void{
    if(Marcianos.cantidad>0)
        Marcianos.cantidad++;
}

public cantidadDeMarcianos():void{
    if(Marcianos.cantidad >0)
        console.log('Quedan en el juego'+Marcianos.cantidad+' marcianos');
    else
        console.log('Felicidades, has ganados!!!');
 }
}

class Computadora{
 private static marcianos_computadora;

 constructor() {
     console.log('Se ha creado computadora');
    Computadora.marcianos_computadora= Marcianos.getMarcianos;   
 }

 public creaMarcianos():void {
     Computadora.marcianos_computadora.creaMarcianos;
  }
 }
 class  Jugador{
private static marcianos_jugador;

constructor() {
    console.log('Se ha creado jugador');
    Jugador.marcianos_jugador= Marcianos.getMarcianos;
 }
public destruirMarciano():void{
    Jugador.marcianos_jugador.derribaMarcianos;
}
}
class Juego{
private static marcianos_juego;
constructor(){
    console.log('Se ha iniciado el juego');
    Juego.marcianos_juego=Marcianos.getMarcianos;
    Juego.main();
}

public static main(): void{
    var computadora = new Computadora(),
        jugador = new Jugador();

    jugador.destruirMarciano();
    jugador.destruirMarciano();        
    jugador.destruirMarciano();                
    computadora.creaMarcianos();
    Juego.marcianos_juego.cantidadDeMarcianos;

  }

}

   let juego =new Juego();
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu código tiene varios problemas y un estilo muy poco ortodoxo incluso para la POO "habitual":

1. Creas todos los atributos (variables de clase) `static`, y creo que no es el comportamiento que quieres implementar.
2. Te refieres a los atributos anteponiendo el nombre de la clase. Para atributos privados debes utilizar `this`
3. Usas nombres con un **guión bajo** en unos atributos si, y en otros no, siendo todos privados, lo cual resulta muy confuso al leer el código. Además tampoco exportas las clases, por lo que no podrás utilizarlas fuera (tener todas las clases juntas en un único fichero sin un aparente orden no es muy útil que digamos).
4. Es horrible crear objetos para imitar una especie de array de esos objetos (Marcianos) y más aún, crear una instancia de sí mismo en el constructor (¿es una especie de Singleton o algo así lo que necesitas?). Marciano (así en singular) debería ser una clase en sí misma (con sus propiedades y sus acciones concretas) y creo que para lo que quieres, deberías guardar un array de marcianos. Para no complicarlo mucho, vamos a obviar esta parte.
5. La lógica de la aplicación está mal distribuida, y creo que muy mal nombrada.

Dicho todo eso, te paso un código que creo que puede resultarte más o menos funcional y autoexplicativo. Quizá quedan demasiadas clases para lo que se pretende, pero he tratado de mantener tu estructura todo lo posible para que te sea familiar.
No puedo probar el código porque no estoy por la oficina ahora mismo, pero debería funcionar.

> Adicionalmente, que sepas que puedes inicializar variables en el cosntructor así:

```
constructor(private logica:LogicaJuego) { }
```

*Esto es **equvalente** a:*

```
private logica:LogicaJuego

constructor(parametroLogica:LogicaJuego){
  this.logica = parametroLogica
}
```

---

### 1) Clase LogicaJuego (vendría a sustituir a tu Marcianos)

```
export class LogicaJuego {
  private _cantidadMarcianos:number;

  constructor(){
    console.log('Se ha creado la logica del juego');
    this._cantidadMarcianos = 10;   
  }

  public getCantidadMarcianos():number {
    return this._cantidadMarcianos;
  }

  public derribaMarciano():void {
    this._cantidadMarcianos--
  }

  public creaMarciano():void{
    this._cantidadMarcianos++
  }

  public informacionJuego():void{
    if(this._cantidadMarcianos >0)
      console.log('Quedan en el juego' + this._cantidadMarcianos + ' marcianos');
    else
      console.log('Felicidades, has ganados!!!');
    }
  }
```

### 2) Clase Computadora

```
export class Computadora {
  private _logica:LogicaJuego;

  constructor(logica:LogicaJuego) {
    console.log('Se ha creado computadora');
    this._logica == logica;
  }

  public creaMarcianos():void {
    this._logica.creaMarciano();
  }
 }
```

### 3) Clase Jugador

```
export class Jugador{
  private _logica:LogicaJuego;

  constructor(logica:LogicaJuego) {
    console.log('Se ha creado jugador');
    this._logica = logica;
  }

  public destruirMarciano():void{
      this._logica.derribaMarciano();
  }
}
```

### 4) Clase Juego

```
export class Juego {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Se ha iniciado el juego');
  }

  public jugar(): void{
      let logicaJuego:LogicaJuego = new LogicaJuego();
      let computadora:Computadora = new Computadora(logica),
      let jugador:Jugador = new Jugador(logica);

      jugador.destruirMarciano();
      jugador.destruirMarciano();        
      jugador.destruirMarciano();                
      computadora.creaMarcianos();
      logica.informacionJuego();
    }
  }
```

### Lanzar app

```
let juego = new Juego();
juego.jugar();
```